# X-Men story identification: Firestarter boy

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, x-men

The story is from a comic book I read in the 90s.

The X-Men discover a mutant boy, maybe 6 to 10 years of age, whose mutant power is **pyrokinesis**.

I faintly remember that the boy was a sweet little kid who seemed to take a liking to the X-Men but after a mob assaulted him he caused serious havoc.

I think the boy was white, and he might have had blond hair. He was younger than the boy in @Shreedhar's story.

There's really not much else I can remember about the story. I've scoured the internet but couldn't find anything even remotely similar.

It could have been a one-off story. His head wasn't on fire so it wasn't Match.

Comment: Is he a twisted firestarter?

Comment: @Valorum the self inflicted, mind detonator? (Oh wait this isn't reddit...)

Answer (score 6):

## The character you are looking for could well be SUNSPOT.

---

Based on the information you provided, the mutant kid:

1. Is Pyrokinetic
2. Manifested his powers when he was assaulted
3. Boy (between the age 6 - 10 years)
4. Comic story released/read in the 90's

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunspot_(comics)#Origin):

> Shortly before his fourteenth birthday (as best can be determined; there are conflicting references) Roberto was playing a soccer game with his team (the Thunderbolts) against their arch-rivals, the Dynamos. ***Racist members of the Dynamos assaulted Roberto during the game, and in response Roberto took matters into his own hands, initiating a fight on the field. While taking a brutal beating, his mutant powers manifested, suddenly transforming him into a creature of solid black solar energy***. Surprised and terrified, people abandoned the stadium, and only his girlfriend, Juliana Sandoval, refused to abandon him.

There are some differences though. He is not a kid but a teenager. Instead of the mob, he was attacked by the opposition football team-members.

Although some points are not exactly the same, they do share a lot of similarities. So, this mutant kid you're looking for could be **Sunspot**.

And you don't have to rely only on Wiki. The ***Marvel Graphic novel [Issue # 4: The New Mutants](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_Graphic_Novel_Vol_1_4)*** presents his origin. Here are 4 pages that suitably reiterate the scenario your describe:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The other divergences are that Bobby was a bit older, a teenager, and didn't gain pyrokinesis until the Reignfire debacle much later. Initially, he was just superstrong (but not invulnerable).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I did mention about him being older. But I had no idea that his powers manifested way later; that's something to remember :) thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Shreedhar but I don't think that's the story I'm looking for. I remember the boy being much younger, and I think he was white. He also had pyrokinesis from the very beginning. I'll edit the question to include those details.

Comment: @E.T. no worries. I'll check and if i find it exactly as you have described, I will change this answer so that you can accept it :) cheers

Comment: @E.T. the only other mutant who closely matches this description is the Match a.k.a Benjamin "Ben" Hamill.

Comment: Sorry, it's not Match either. I checked the pictures on the suggested characters so far but they don't fit what I remember. It's possible that the story wasn't an origin story for an X-Man at all. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Addendum to my previous comment: I mean, it was definitely an X-Men comic book, but it could be that this child didn't reappear in later stories and didn't join the X-Men.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is Rusty (Russell Collins), who was introduced in X-Factor #1 (1986). From the Marvel Database:

"Russell Collins was the son of a sailor who died in a war. After his mother died, he was sent to live with his Uncle Ted and worked at his hardware store. Rusty's uncle considered him a whiner and shipped him off to the Navy when he turned sixteen. Docking at the San Diego Naval Yard after months at sea, Rusty's mutant pyrokinetic powers activated when kissing a prostitute named Emma in an alley. Causing her serious burns, Rusty fled but was captured by military police. While in custody his superior, Chief Jack Fisher, attempted to kill Rusty when his powers erupted again, freeing him. Afraid Rusty would report him, Fisher notified X-Factor, who the world believed were mutant exterminators but were actually the original X-Men in disguise. After an initial battle, X-Factor took Rusty into their care."
[image]

Comment: Sadly, it's not Rusty either. "Rusty's mutant pyrokinetic powers activated when kissing a prostitute named Emma in an alley." <-- This doesn't fit what I remember from the story. It was definitely a young, elementary school age child. It could have been a one-off story.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Sunspot? It doesn't fit your description perfectly (he is a teenager and is not assaulted by a mob but by another football team) but his origin story is explained [Marvel Graphic Novel Vol 1 4](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_Graphic_Novel_Vol_1_4) (released in 1982) and a short summary can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunspot_(comics)#Origin):

> When Roberto was playing a soccer game with his team , racist members
>   of the opposing team assaulted him, and Roberto responded by
>   initiating a fight on the field. While taking a brutal beating, his
>   mutant powers manifested, suddenly transforming him into a creature of
>   solid black solar energy. Surprised and terrified, people abandoned
>   the stadium, and only his girlfriend Juliana refused to abandon him